# How to list all files in an s3 folder using AWS-SDK gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I wanted to show a list of all files in an s3 folder so I can get all the last modified dates so I can determine what files has been changed.

I tried using objects.with_prefix('Folder1') it give me a full list but also contain Folder1.1 key

I don't know if i needed to use delimiter but I couldn't find anything how to use delimiter in aws sdk.

Thanks so much in advance!

I'm using 'aws-sdk' gem

Here is my bucket structure
 -Folder1
   -File1
   -File2
   -Folder.1.1

Here is my code

```
bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
data = bucket.objects.with_prefix('Folder1/')
data.each do |object|
    puts "#{object.key}\t#{object.last_modified}";
end
```

Comment: did you get solution for it?

Comment: NONE of the answers here fetch more than the first page of results. If you have more than 1000 objects THIS WILL RETURN INCOMPLETE RESULTS.

Comment: @radiospiel is right. If you want to fetch beyond the first 1000 objects, you need to [iterate through the pages of results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/#Paging_Responses).

Answer (score 43):

Too late answer but better than never.

You can do

```
s3_bucket.objects.with_prefix('folder_name').collect(&:key)
```

According to official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/ObjectCollection.html)

**Updates:**
SDK V3

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = client.list_objects_v2({
  bucket: "BucketName", # required
  prefix: "FolderName", 
})
```

Comment: With version 2 it is:
`s3_bucket.objects(prefix: 'folder_name').collect(&:key)`

Answer (score 16):

You can use this small piece of code for getting list of files for a specific folder.

```
 s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'ap-southeast-1', access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] )
 data_files = s3.bucket(bucket_name).objects(prefix: 'prefix/', delimiter: 'delimiter').collect(&:key)
```

Comment: What to specify as delimiter if you want to get all keys with a prefix. I don't want to delimit with anything.

Answer (score 8):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_objects_v2-instance_method

SDK V3 has the prefix option for client!

`resp = client.list_objects_v2({
  bucket: "BucketName", # required
  prefix: "FolderName", 
})`

Answer (score 3):

Currently I am also stuck with this problem. So far  solution is to fetch all the objects and to filter them later:

```
data = bucket.objects(bucketname, prefix: 'Folder1')

data_without_folders = data.select { |obj| !(obj.key =~ /\/$/) }
```

For delimiter, you just have to pass it in bucket.objects call like:

```
data = bucket.objects(bucketname, prefix: 'prefix', delimiter: 'delimiter')
```

If better solution is available, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Let's remember that the S3 is not a file system, so even the 'folder/' is an object.

Now if you want to get the files for a specific path, you can use the **start_after**. For example, if you have in your S3 bucket a list of objects like this.

```
pictures/
pictures/horse.jpg
pictures/dog.jpg
pictures/cat.jpg
lion.jpg
```

You can get all the pictures from the picture/ path by doing the following:

```
 s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'ap-southeast-1', access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] )
 pictures = s3.bucket(bucket_name).objects(prefix: 'pictures/', delimiter: '', start_after: 'pictures/').collect(&:key)
```

The output is going to be only all the pictures keys without the folder/:

- pictures/horse.jpg
- pictures/dog.jpg
- pictures/cat.jpg