# Best way to return an array of files from Amazon S3 and sort by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get an array of files from an AWS S3 Bucket, then sort them by date uploaded, to choose the latest file and display it in a view.

I got to the point of doing something like this, using the Dir method in Ruby

```
Dir['*'].sort_by{ |f| File.ctime(f) }
```

However, I can't figure out how to change the working directory to the Amazon S3 directory.

Perhaps there is an easier way to do this altogether? Other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392931/how-to-list-all-files-in-an-s3-folder-using-aws-sdk-gem-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the AWS SDK is fairly straightforward.

Once you have the array of files:

```
bucket.objects.sort_by &:last_modified
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, much easier than I was making it.

Comment: Thanks works perfect, but how can we sort by DESC or ASC?

Comment: nvm, I slove it using reverse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

bucket.objects.sort_by { |object| object.last_modified }.reverse