# How to get S3 objects created by current user in AWS SDK (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using AWS SDK, is it programmatically possible to get the list of all bucket objects created by a particular user (current user)?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'  # v2: require 'aws-sdk'

region = 'us-west-2'
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: region)

s3.buckets.limit(50).each do |b|
  puts "#{b.name}"
end
```

**[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-get-buckets.html)**

Also, this will list the objects of a bucket:

`s3_bucket.objects.with_prefix('folder_name').collect(&:key)`

With version 2 it is:

`s3_bucket.objects(prefix: 'folder_name').collect(&:key)`

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392931/how-to-list-all-files-in-an-s3-folder-using-aws-sdk-gem-in-ruby-on-rails)**

Combination of both will help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to identify the "user" who created an object.

When an API call is made to Amazon S3 to upload/create an object, the credentials are checked to confirm that they are permitted to perform the operation. Once this has been confirmed, the object that is created is "owned" by the AWS Account, not a specific user within the account.

You could [Enable Object-Level Logging for an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html), but this only outputs log information. It does not associate an object with a user.